# how to concat the rows in postgres sql using case statement from 4tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

```
emp_id   project_id  TASK_11     TASK_12     TASK_13    TASK_14
42527     4           no         no          no         yes
42527     4           no         yes         no         no
42527     4           yes        no          no         no
42527     4            no        no         yes         no
```

in the above table i want to display all emp_id's are need to come once. means

```
emp_id   project_id  TASK_11     TASK_12     TASK_13    TASK_14
42527     4           yes        yes         yes            yes
```

i want to display  like this am using 
below command  please let me know where need to modify

```
select distinct(b.emp_id),c.project_id,
(CASE when task_id='11' then 'yes'
    else 'no'
END) as "TASK_11",
(CASE 
    when task_id='12' then 'yes'
else 'no'
END) as "TASK_12",
(CASE 
    when task_id='13' then 'yes'
    else 'no'
END) as "TASK_13",
(CASE 
    when task_id='14' then 'yes'
    else 'no'
end) as "TASK_14"
FROM "Projects".user_projects a,
    "Projects".user_clients b,
    "Projects".project_tasks c,
    "Projects".user_tasks d,
    "Projects".projects e
WHERE  c.id = d.id AND a.id = b.id AND e.client_id=b.client_id 
    AND a.project_id=c.project_id and b.client_id=e.client_id
    and(b.emp_id = ANY (ARRAY[45262, 42572, 42527, 40904, 808, 909, 109, 
        147, 70707, 41111, 41041, 80808, 4235, 22, 428882, 4001100,
        40904, 42527, 42581, 42581, 12, 12, 42501, 42501, 202, 47100,
        42501, 4001100, 6389, 20240, 11662, 23556, 30480])) 
    AND e.project_name = 'wms' and c.project_id=4
```

Comment: So quick question, I assume these tasks made at different times, and you want that if they completed the task then the final result of that particular record should be yes if they have done it otherwise no?

Comment: The last time i checked `DISTINCT` wasn't a PostgreSQL function.. You are using it as a function `distinct(b.emp_id)` properly you meant to use `distinct on (b.emp_id)` which keep the "first" row off b.emp_id

Comment: Raymond is right. `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. `distinct (a),b,c` is exactly the same thing as `distinct a,(b),c` or `distinct a,b,c`. It always applies to all columns (expressions) in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a straightforward conditional aggregate query directly running `MAX` on your logical `CASE` statements.

Additionally, consider re-factoring your SQL to use explicit joins (a 25+ year standard introduced in ANSI-92) and not the older, hard to read and maintain implicit joins as you current have. There is no change in performance but arguably easier to read and maintain with explicit `JOIN`.

```
SELECT b.emp_id, c.project_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN task_id='11' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS "TASK_11",
       MAX(CASE WHEN task_id='12' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS "TASK_12",
       MAX(CASE WHEN task_id='13' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS "TASK_13",
       MAX(CASE WHEN task_id='14' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS "TASK_14"
FROM "Projects".user_projects a
INNER JOIN "Projects".user_clients b ON b.id = a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN "Projects".project_tasks c ON c.project_id = a.project_id
INNER JOIN "Projects".user_tasks d ON c.id = d.id
INNER JOIN "Projects".projects e ON e.client_id = b.client_id 
WHERE b.emp_id = ANY (ARRAY[45262, 42572, 42527, 40904, 808, 909, 109, 
                            147, 70707, 41111, 41041, 80808, 4235, 22, 428882, 4001100,
                            40904, 42527, 42581, 42581, 12, 12, 42501, 42501, 202, 47100,
                            42501, 4001100, 6389, 20240, 11662, 23556, 30480])
  AND e.project_name = 'wms' and c.project_id = 4
GROUP BY b.emp_id, c.project_id
```

Comment: I do not understand you. What is a *cross table* query? Please note I re-written your implicit joins for explicit joins which should be equivalent. Does this query result in an error? Does it not produce your desired output?

Comment: If this worked, why do you need another solution? Also, you do not mention this in original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate boolean values with bool_or() and bool_and()

In your case you should use bool_or()

```
select emp_id, project_id, 
       bool_or(TASK_11) task_11,
       bool_or(TASK_11) task_12,
       bool_or(TASK_11) task_13,
       bool_or(TASK_11) task_14
  from "your_query"
 group by emp_id, project_id
```

Btw. your query seems to be incorrect in few places. First is distinct (as Raymond Nijland and a_horse_with_no_name) also this part looks strange "c.id = d.id AND a.id = b.id" until id is in fact user_id.